# resize ext4 container file

Tags: partitioning, dd

I created an ext4 file container with 16GB of space.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./container_16GB.img bs=1M count=16384
mkfs.ext4 container.img
```

It is nor problem to mount this container file but is it also possible to resize it?

If yes, how can I resize it to 20GB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can resize the filrsystem.  The exact method depends on if you are growing or shrinking it, what tools you have and what filesystem you are using.  In broad terns -

To grow a container is conceptually easy -

- Grow the underlying file.  You could do something as simple as "catting" bytes to the end of the underlying file, or use truncate to make the file larger, or use tools provided by vm software like qemu-image resize.   Be mindful of the difference between a preallocated and sparse disk.  A sparse disk may appear larger then it is on disk and could lead to issues down the road if the disk on the host runs out but is faster to create and more compact. I'd always use a preallocated disk for a vm.
- Use a tool lile resize2fs / resize4fs (same thing, different distro) or the equivalent for your filesystem to grow the filesystem.

Shrinking a filesystem is harder.  It requires unmounting the filesystem, shrinking it (also wuth resize2fs or equivalent), then truncating the disk **but ensuring the truncated disk is no smaller then what you gave told resize2fs.   The way I normally do this is to use resize2fs to shrink the disk SMALLER then the new target size, then shrink the disk to the desired size, then grow the filesystem to the new size if the disk.

Other -

If you are resizing swao, don't. Unmount it, resize the file, reformat swap.  If the system is live and using more memory then you have you can create a second temporary swap file and mount that befire deactivating the one you want to resize - but this will nail performance.

Some OS's/filesystems (Mainly Windows ones) will need to be defragged before they can be shrunk. Some system files may need to be dusabled/deleted before the filesystem can be shrunk depending where they are.